# Unordered Map C++14

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

I am able to traverse this map from beginning to end using this way.
But I want to traverse this map from end to beginning so that the
elements.
printed above are now printed in reverse order. Please help how to do
this.

Consider that i have the map's second argument as the class help I have
created and I want to access each member of that class as well just as I
did in the for loop I have created.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class help
{
public:
    int freq;
    vector<int> indexes;
    help()
    {
        freq=0;
    }
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<char,help> m;
    for(auto x : m)
    {   
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second.freq<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<x.second.indexes.size();i++)
            cout<<x.second.indexes[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unordered means *unordered*. "Reverse" doesn't even make sense, as even the order of *forward* iteration can change whenever the container needs to resize. If you're relying on order in an unordered container, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: And why are you including `<bits/stdc++.h>` rather than `<unordered_map>`, `<vector>` and `<iostream>`?

Comment: Unordered means *unordered*. The standard does not require the observerd ordering of a given collection of elements be the same on *consecutive runs of the same program* [see the notes of `std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it with ordered map then?

Comment: #include<bits/stdc++.h> lets me include all other library functions under it.

Comment: @RishabhJain: Problem is, it's not standard (so other compilers need not provide that header), your code's requirements are no longer obvious, you have no good reason to even want "all other library functions" anyway (it results in compiling a ton of stuff you will never use, ie: longer compile times for no reason), and since you were lazy enough to say `using namespace std;`, now your namespace is a potential minefield. You should include only what you require, and don't import the entire `std::` namespace -- import what you use, and/or just learn to say `std::`.